# Inserting symbols with fontspec => Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: fonts, symbols, luatex, fontspec

I'm attempting to insert the arrow and thick hyphen symbols ‣ and ⁃, `U+2023` and `U+2043` respectively, into my document. I tried compiling the following with `lualatex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
  \symbol{^^^^2023}
  \symbol{^^^^2043}
\end{document}
```

However, I get the compilation errors

```latex
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
‣
  \symbol{^^^^2023}
```

and

```latex
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
⁃
  \symbol{^^^^2043}
```

What does the error mean in this case, and how could I insert the symbols into my document? Changing compilers from `lualatex` to something else is not an option.

Comment: the ^^^^^-notation inserts a char not a number, use `\symbol{"2023}` (but you need a font with this symbols)..

Comment: or simply use the character so use `^^^^2043` (no `\symbol`) or just use `⁃`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The symbols alone produce only whitespace, but that is most likely because I'm using Latin Modern as my main font.

Comment: @SeSodesa sure but `\symbol{some number}` just inserts the \char with that number it doesn't change font so if ⁃ doesn't work, \symbol will not either (the log file will tell you if there is a missing character in the font)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special syntax `^^^^2023` means *insert the character with Unicode code point `U+2023`* at the input level.

As an example, typing `^^^^0061^^^^0062^^^^0063` is *exactly* the same as typing `abc` (and the same as `^^61^^62^^63`, by the way).

The command `\symbol{<number>}` means *typeset the glyph at slot `<number>` in the current font.

Thus the two ways are at different levels: *input* for the former, *output* for the latter.

You can use the hexadecimal representation with `\symbol`, but with the required markup: `\symbol{"2023}`. You can as well input `\symbol{8227}` or even, for what it's worth,

```
\symbol{`^^^^2023}
```

using the alphabetical constant representation. But it would be a waste of resources, because `^^^^2023` would give the same result.

**Important remark.** The `^^^^` notation requires *lowercase* digits `abcdef`, whereas the `"` notation requires *uppercase* `ABCDEF`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\char` *without* enclosing its argument in curly braces, or use `\symbol` *with* curly braces.

[image]

I used `Noto Sans` and `Noto Serif`, as LuaTeX's default font family (Latin Modern) does not feature glyphs for either `\symbol{"2023}` or `\symbol{"2043}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
%% 'Noto Sans' and 'Noto Serif' happen to feature the required glyphs
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
  \symbol{"2023}a\symbol{"2043} \quad \char"2023 a\char"2043

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
  \symbol{"2023}a\symbol{"2043} \quad \char"2023 a\char"2043
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\symbol` should be preferred. Something like `\char"2043A` would be very puzzling for the user. Or even `\char"2043 A`, where the space is “mysteriously” disappearing.

Comment: Also, I get the following in my log file ```Missing character: There is no ‣ (U+2023) in font [lmmono12-regular]:!
Missing character: There is no ⁃ (U+2043) in font [lmmono12-regular]:!``` So the characters seem to be missing for some reason.

Comment: I meant to say that even after loading the fonts you mentioned, the fonts didn't get loaded properly. The appearance of my text changed, but the missing symbols still didn't show. I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: @SeSodesa - Please clarify what you mean by "the fonts didn't get loaded properly". Was it maybe because they aren't installed (yet) on your system? That would explain why LuaLaTeX had to fall back on the default font, which is from the Latin Modern family. I used these fonts precisely because they do feature the glyphs you expressed some interest in. I certainly made no claim whatsoever -- either explicitly or implicitly -- that `Noto Sans` and `Noto Serif` are installed on everybody's TeX system. For what it's worth, they can be downloaded for free from https://www.google.com/get/noto/.

Comment: @SeSodesa - You commented, "So the characters seem to be missing for some reason." The glyphs are definitely *not* missing in either `Noto Sans` or `Noto Serif`. Of couse, the glyphs are indeed missing -- as I had already noted explicitly in my answer and as you then rediscovered -- in the fallback font (from the Latin Modern font family) that LuaLaTeX loads in case the argument of `\setmainfont`/`\setsansfont`/`\setmonofont` cannot be loaded successfully. Not being the designer of the Latin Modern fonts, I possess no information as to *why* the two glyphs aren't present in the LM family.